# Connection Timed Out

Tags: php, mysql

Get a message
 Connection Timed Out

Is there another way to get the result without a load on the database

```
$B1=$_REQUEST['B1'];
if($B1){
$T1=strtotime($_REQUEST['T1']);
$T2=strtotime($_REQUEST['T2']);
if($B1){
$datach=" `date_time` between '$T1' and '$T2' ";
}else{
$datach=" date_time>=$Timestamp ";
}
$query=mysql_query("select * from euser where `show`='0' order by id desc ");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$blockid=$row['id'];
$links=mysql_query("select * from rafia_news where usre=$blockid and type=0 and $datach ");
$links2=mysql_query("select * from rafia_news where usre=$blockid and type=1 and $datach ");
$links3=mysql_query("select * from rafia_news where usre=$blockid and type=2 and $datach ");
$count=mysql_num_rows($links);
$count2=mysql_num_rows($links2);
$count3=mysql_num_rows($links3);


    <tr>
    <td><? echo $row['title'];?></td>
    <td width="134"><? echo $count ; ?></td>
    <td width="111"><? echo $count2 ; ?></td>
    <td width="111"><? echo $count3 ; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements to begin with. Also those 3 queries can be done in one.

Comment: how do I do this

Comment: The `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){` is never closed, whats in your error logs? Shortcut `select * from rafia_news where usre=$blockid and type between 0 and 2 and $datach` Better would be to join `euser`.

Comment: I've already closed it on another line
I want to know every member who wrote a news story
Where number 1 equals the number of news
No. 2 Number of articles
No. 0 Number of investigations
  I want the result of each member's work in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need number of rows per type, you can merge those 3 queries as below, that would significantly reduce the load:

```
SELECT count(usre), type FROM rafia_news WHERE usre=$blockid and type in (0, 1, 2) and $datach GROUP BY type
```

Secondly, **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** *mysql**-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Here is the updated code:

```
<?php
$B1=$_REQUEST['B1'];
if($B1){
    $T1=strtotime($_REQUEST['T1']);
    $T2=strtotime($_REQUEST['T2']);
    if($B1){
        $datach=" `date_time` between '$T1' and '$T2' ";
    }else{
        $datach=" date_time>=$Timestamp ";
    }
    $query=mysql_query("select * from euser where `show`='0' order by id desc ");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $blockid=$row['id'];
        $countRecords[0] = $countRecords[1] = $countRecords[2] = 0;
        $links=mysql_query("select count(usre), type from rafia_news where usre=$blockid and type in (0, 1, 2) and $datach GROUP BY type");
        while($countRows = mysql_fetch_array($links)) {
            $countRecords[$countRows[1]] = $countRows[0];
        }

        <tr>
            <td><? echo $row['title'];?></td>
<td width="134">
    <? echo $countRecords[0] ; ?></td>
<td width="111">
    <? echo $countRecords[1] ; ?></td>
<td width="111">
    <? echo $countRecords[2] ; ?></td>
</tr>
?>
```

Comment: How to view the result  <? echo $count ; ?>

Comment: If you using `mysql` and not `mysqli`, you can use `$row=mysql_fetch_array($query)` in the same way, as you have already used.

Comment: Thank you
Do not get the result and get the same error
The question has been modified with full code
please help

Comment: [07-Aug-2017 14:57:52 Africa/Cairo] PHP Warning:  ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/sahrarco/public_html/monthxxxx.php on line 73     line 73  $countRecords = ksort($countRecords);

Comment: Check if the query is returning any output. I have updated the code too, for the same.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but the report figures out the mistakes

Comment: What _report figures_? and what are the mistakes?

Comment: http://www.al3asma.com/monthxxxx.php This is the file link ميرفت أسحق  265  50  15     The correct is   0 0 0    Because it did not work since 07/31 /2017 to 08/01/2017

Comment: It did gave me some data. I hope you are doing proper debugging by checking error logs, console logs, etc.

Comment: There are no errors in file errors
But the figures are incorrect
There are people who do not have news and the result is the news and when entering the database I can not find news

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand arabic. But I think, you should look at `$countRecords` variable. Is it sorted correctly based on keys as type? does it have data for all `type` values? those are additional checks that you would have to perform. I made a tiny update by adding `$countRecords[0] = $countRecords[1] = $countRecords[2] = 0;`, hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for helping me
I think the problem is  $countRecords[$countRows[1]] = $countRows[0]

Comment: Thank you for helping me The last code works successfully and without errors thanking you

Comment: Phew! Finally!! :)